# How to call a function inside a function ?Odoo9 Validation

Tags: python, validation, odoo, odoo-9

I have a added a boolean field in `product.pricelist.item`

```
class product_pricelist_item(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.pricelist.item'

    myfield = fields.Boolean(string="CheckMark")
```

Now there are multiple lines in `product.pricelist.item`.

(Validation)
I want that the user is not allowed to make `True` multiple `myfield` one one field can be `True` at a time.

I tried doing this in `product.pricelist.item` by giving it a counter and passing the counter the number of `myfields` which are `True`.

But this is giving me error.

> global name '_get_counter' is not defined

```
def _get_counter(self):
    for r in self:
        p=[]
        p= r.env['product.pricelist.item'].search_read([('myfield', '=', True)], ['myfield'])
        counter = len(p)
    return counter

@api.constrains('myfield')
def _check_myfield(self):
    counter = _get_counter(self)
    for r in self:
        if counter > 1:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError("Multiple myfield In a PriceList of a Product is not allowed.")
```

Now the second question is :-

When you create a pricelist-item and click save in pricelist then it does not reflect the data in the database. When you click the pricelist save it reflects the data...why is this so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `self` we can call method of current class.

Try with following code:

Replace code

```
counter = _get_counter(self)
```

with

```
counter = self._get_counter()
```

Comment: Error:- `_get_counter() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: `counter = self._get_counter()` Works Fine.

Answer (score 1):

The loop in `_get_counter` does not affect the result and the search did not depend on records so you can use:

```
def _get_counter(self):

    pricelist_obj = self.env['product.pricelist.item']
    counter = len(pricelist_obj.search_read([('myfield', '=', True)], ['myfield']))
    return counter

@api.constrains('myfield')
def _check_myfield(self):

    counter = self._get_counter()
    if counter > 1:
        raise exceptions.ValidationError("Multiple myfield In a PriceList of a Product is not allowed.")
```